# How do i update data in my Django Rest Framework project before it is commited to database

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am creating my first Django Rest Framework project. My models.py has a model Location

I want to ensure proper format of the data in the country and state field by converting them to lower case. My intention is to do it through the def create and def update function in the serializer. However my application execution is never reaching this functions

```
class Location(models.Model):
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=False)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.country + ' ' + self.state
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'locations'
        unique_together = ['country', 'state']
```

My serializers.py file has LocationSerializer defined as below

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Location 

class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta: 
        model = Location
        fields = ['id', 'country_code', 'country', 'state', 'date_created', 'date_updated']
        
    def create(self, validated_data):
        print ("in create")
        return Location(**validated_data)
        
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        print ("in update")
        return instance
```

```
from rest_framework import viewsets 
from .serializers import LocationSerializer
from .models import Location
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend

from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

class LocationsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Location.objects.all()
    
    serializer_class = LocationSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['country', 'state']
    ordering_fields = ['country', 'state']
    ordering = ['country']
    
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        print ("In perform_create")
        serializer.save(state=self.request.state.lower())
```

My add/update is working through the /admin endpoint. However the create and update methods are never called. Is it the rightway to go about it?

Comment: Does your view use this serializer? Can you post your view as well?

Comment: @NickODell I have updated views.py details. The perform_create function in views.py is also never reached

Comment: Nope when you call from /admin endpoint your create and update functions will not call but database validation will call for example country_code is required, you will not commit in database until you fill the country_code.

Comment: If you want to call create/update functions written in serializers you have to make api/endpoint to make it callable.

Comment: Thanks @TanveerAhmad. That helped. I was checking add/update through the admin endpoint. When i checked through swagger-ui, the create and update functions in serializers.py were invoked

Comment: Good to hear that. You are welcome broo